# Facebook iOS SDK too slow

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios

I have recently wired up my application to use the Facebook iOS SDK (http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). The integration works fine, but the pages loads really slow. It takes really a long time to load the login screen. Login action takes more than 10-60 seconds.

I didn't have this problem with [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/108). Am I missing something? Is there a way to optimize this?

**Update**

I did scan the activity through HTTP Scoop over Wi-Fi which revealed something interesting, there are some .js and .css files that are taking a lot of time in the new Facebook iOS SDK (login.php, ar7ed2ft.css, 4wj242ne.js, abl6sgyy.js,) where as the old one was zippy. How to let Facebook know about it?

New Facebook iOS SDK

[image: New FB iOS SDK Activity Monitor]

Old Facebook Connect

[image: Old FB Connect]

Comment: When you run Instruments against your application, where do you see the bottlenecks?

Comment: I don't see any bottlenecks in object allocations or activity monitor...is there something I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Implement OAuth 2.0 yourself. It just uses HTTPS, extremely easy to implement. In my experience, it was easier than using their confusing, document-less SDK. Important is getting authentication token. You can access all their graphs with it.

If you implement it yourself, you can choose login screen dialog design as one of:

- touch
- WAP

WAP is uglier because it's for older phones, but if you really need it, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk

Comment: This is the older version I moved away from. I want to use Facebook Graph API